# php crontab not working while execution from browser is successful

Tags: php, cron

recently i ran over the following problem with a php script I was running in the crontab of my hosting provider.  The script is used to parse an xml file from a remote location. The initial script (the one set to run in the crontab) is calling another script (which is the one that does the xml parsing) through include:

`include 'myXMLreader.php';`

When the script is executed from the browser, everything runs perfectly (the xml is parsed and stored in a DB).  However, when run from the cron, I get the following error:

***"Warning:  myXMLreader::read() [xmlreader.read]: An Error Occured while reading in..."*** and the script stops.

The strange thing is that the **same** script was executed from the crontab perfectly a few days ago.

In order to execute the script I am using the following line in my cron manager:

`00 01 * * * php -q /home/my_domain/public_html/my_parser_script.php`

I have also set the time limit of the script execution to zero (0) in order to avoid getting kicked off due to time limit violation (since the xml parsing takes more than 6min to finish).

`set_time_limit(0);`

Any help/suggestion of why this may be happening?

Tx

Comment: what user ID is this cron job running under, and you MAY need to specify the full path to php in the cron job, e.g. `/usr/bin/php -q etc...` As a general note: PHP on the CLI by default usually has time/memory limits disabled. Those are usually only applied when in SAPI (in-webserver) mode only.

Comment: might be a file permission issue.

Comment: I have asked my hosting provider to let me know of the user ID running the cron and the full path of the php (by the way, is there a way that I can find out the latter by myself?). In the meantime, let me tell you that both of my php files have been set to 755 permissions

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible this is a local DNS problem ?
You easily test this be adding the IP and domain (of where the xml file is located) to your servers /etc/hosts file.

Comment: this is a shared hosting plan, so I don't think I could change the /etc/hosts file